# Vb.net webbrowser always downloads file when showing javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net, file, download, browser

i'm making a simple app that asks a remote server via webbrowser, but, if the remote page is replying with javascript, instead of showing the text the browser always prompt to download the search.js file.
is there a way to only show the source instead of downloading the file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading the .js file is the default behavior of IE(which is used by the webbrowser control. If you want to display the source, you could download the the file and set `DocumentText` to display the source.

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this by this should work

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();    
var source = client.DownloadString("http://example.com/somescript.js");

webBrowser1.DocumentText = source;
```

Comment: One more thing, do you know how to make this work if you are logged out from that website?